# Spring-retry не срабатывает

Tags: java, spring

```
public void method1(){
    method2();
}


@Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500,multiplier=2))
public void method2(){      
}
```

Почему spring-retry не срабатывает при нахождении метода 1 и метода 2 в одном классе при вызове метода 1.

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что функциональность @Retryable реализована с помощью АОП. В Spring используется динамическая реализация АОП, которая заключается в создании прокси для всех целевых объектов. Прокси-объект перехватывает вызовы к `method2()` и применяет к ним *советы*. Но прокси-объект не может перехватывать вызовы внутри целевого объекта. Поэтому на вызов метода `method2()` из `method1()` нельзя навесить *совет* проверяющий выброс исключения и повторяющий вызов.